# Как сделать яндекс-панораму адаптивной

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Имеется код яндекс-панорамы, допустим, такой

```
<script src="https://panoramas.api-maps.yandex.ru/embed/1.x/?lang=ru&ll=27.51726518%2C53.91002997&ost=dir%3A75.882735%2C8.369128~span%3A119.99999999999999%2C62.525540588662224&size=690%2C400&l=stv"></script>
```

Как сделать панораму адаптивной? width-height как я понял тут нету...

Comment: Адаптивной к чему? На чем запускать  собрались то?

Comment: Публикация на сайте, отображение в браузере

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался - поле size  нужно оставит пустым

```
<script src="https://panoramas.api-maps.yandex.ru/embed/1.x/?lang=ru&amp;ll=27.51726518%2C53.91002997&amp;ost=dir%3A75.882735%2C8.369128~span%3A119.99999999999999%2C62.525540588662224&amp;size=%2C400&amp;l=stv" type="text/javascript"></script>
```